# WPF - bind ItemControl to ListBox Selector

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, itemscontrol

I have an ItemControl which is binded to a filtered view of an observable collection. I would like to be able to select an item of the ItemControl like I can do with an ListBoxItem. So that I can synchronize my ItemControl with the selector of the existing ListBox. Is that possible?

Here the code of the ItemControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding JointsModelPartView }" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">            
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">                        
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding posx1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding posy1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>                    
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="Point">                        
                        <Ellipse Fill="AntiqueWhite"
                                 Stroke="Black"
                                 Width="10"
                                 Height="10"
                                 Margin="-5,-5,5,5"                                     
                                 DataContext="{StaticResource vm}"                                    
                                 Focusable="True"                                     
                                 >                           
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>                                
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="Ellipse_SelectElement" TargetObject="{Binding}" />                                   
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="Ellipse_MouseMove" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="Ellipse_UnselectElement" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <Ellipse.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextActionsView}">
                                <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RCommand}"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Ellipse.ContextMenu>
                    </Ellipse>                        
                </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Here the code of the existing ListBoxItem:

```
<ListBox Name="Model" ItemsSource="{Binding ModelPartView, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1" Margin="1,0,0,0" Padding="5,0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,2">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MPtype}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  />                          
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                
            <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextActionsView}">
                    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">  
                            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RCommand}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>                          
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListBox.ContextMenu>                
        </ListBox>
```

I would be happy about any hints.

Comment: You should use a ListBox or Listview with GridView instead of ItemsControl. Because ItemsControl does not have a Selector.

Comment: Could you please give me a short example ?